# Spinner inside DisplayAlert (Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I want to make a display alert in my app but I want instead of an ok or something else button a spinner untile I close the display alert in my code.

I searched already in the internet but i could not find any solution for my problem.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addSubview is not available in UIAlertView since iOS7. You will need to make a custom view for this. Luckily for you there are already a lot of existing libraries for this task.

Here is one that works for Xamarin as well [KLCPopup_Bindings](http://github.com/iamIcarus/KLCPopup_Bindings)